# Using a button (in my repeater) to show hidden information using javascript but doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms

first post here.

So I have a repeater in my html and in that repeater I have a button as shown below:

```
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Contact</button>
                <p style="display: none" id="contact"><%# Eval("Email") %></p>
```

What I want to do is to have a hidden field of information that's why I have display: none to hide it. Then every time I press the button I want the email to appear below it.

I have some javascript code to do this:

```
    var element = document.querySelectorAll(".btn btn-info");

    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        element[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            this.style.display = "block";
        }, false)
    }
```

But I can't seem to get it working. Every time I press the button nothing happens.

If anyone could help me out that would be really awesome. Thank you!

Comment: `this.style.display` in this scenario, `this` keyword would be pointing to `button` tag and not the `p` tag.

Comment: `this`, in the context of the event handler, will refer to the clicked button. So all you're doing is making the button visible...which of course it already is. That's why nothing useful appears to happen. You need to target the `<p>` which is the [sibling](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+find+sibling&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=javascript+find+sibling&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.68095j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change your JavaScript to this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".btn.btn-info");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
        // Suppose this.nextElementSibling is the email hidden field
        this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to do the trick. I'm just confused at what nextElementSibling is supposed to do. Quick google says " Get the HTML content of the next sibling of a list item". Confused because there really isn't a list in my html. Unless it just means get the next element after <button> which is <p>

Comment: `nextElementSibling` is the nearest HTML element after the current element, which has the same parent as the current one. In this example, the `nextElementSibling` of the `<button>` is `<p>`.

Comment: @Tim where did you read that definition? MDN (which is usually the highest-quality documentation of all things HTML and javascript) at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling says "returns the element immediately following the specified one in its parent's children list" . Hopefully that's a bit clearer? The "list" is the list of all elements which are children of the target element's parent. i.e. the list all elements which have the same parent as the current one

Comment: @ADyson I found it at: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_nextelementsibling.asp. I didn't know about MDN, I will definitely be using that from now on

Comment: @Tim w3schools is, unfortunately, notorious among developers for its sloppy definitions, poor explanations and outright incorrect or obsolete information, in too many cases. It's a bit more beginner friendly than other sites, to its credit, but at the same time it actually often teaches those beginners bad habits or the wrong info. In this case, it was just a bit unclear, but either way I would try and avoid it if you can. There are better JS tutorial sites out there. MDN is quite technical in its wording, but it's usually very accurate.